# How to select via regex all class notations in css file

Tags: css, regex

By having a css file with css rules, I'd like to select only css class (i.e.) `.tblGenFixed`  but not css values for a rule (i.e.) `opacity: 0.3` .

This is my regex:
`/(\.([\w_]+))/g`

This is my alternative solution but it doesn't work
`/(?!\{)(\.([\w_]+))(?!\})/g`

I have set an example in regex101 here https://regex101.com/r/gG4nN4/1

How can I ignore css rule values ?

Comment: How about this? ----> https://regex101.com/r/gG4nN4/3

Comment: it works for classes, but I cannot rely on spaces before a class, what if I have a rule for two classes ? see my update https://regex101.com/r/gG4nN4/4

Comment: [Here is another one](https://regex101.com/r/gG4nN4/7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this : [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

A value will have a digit after the dot. Luckily, valid CSS class names cannot start with a digit :)

Your regexp has to match a dot first, then a letter or - or _

**!** if you look for whitespace before the dot, a value like .5 will match ...

Try this one : `(\.([a-zA-Z_-]{1}[\w-_]+))`

**Edit** :

See this too : [Regex to match a CSS class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329090/regex-to-match-a-css-class-name)

`-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*`

Relevant quote :

*Basically, a name must begin with an underscore (_), a hyphen (-), or a letter(a–z), followed by any number of hyphens, underscores, letters, or numbers. There is a catch: if the first character is a hyphen, the second character must be a letter or underscore, and the name must be at least 2 characters long.*

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how your CSS is written, you might be able to get what you are looking for by requiring whitespace before the period:

```
 \W/(\.([\w_]+))/g
```

Here's [a fork of your regex](https://regex101.com/r/qL8eE9/1).

Depending on what you are looking for, you might want to skip one of those capture groups:

```
\W\.([\w_]+)
```

I'd also warn against parsing CSS with a regex without manually examining the results.

Comment: `\w` also includes `_` in its character set, but not `-`, a valid character for CSS classes.